# Magento: Changing the number of product column in different category

Tags: magento

There are a few answers posted out there but non of them works for me.

So what I want to achieve is on Category A I am showing 4 columns per row with left sidebar, and on Category B I want to create 5 columns with no sidebar at all.

What I have tried:

1) Edit Category B Custom Design Tab Page Layout to 1 Column, In Custom Layout Update add the following code:

`<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>5</columns></action>
    </reference>`

Cleared cache and nothing changes, Category B is still 4 columns.

2) Create CMS Pages with 1 column layout and use this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="22" columnCount="5"     template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Products show up but its still 4 columns.

3) Checked the CSS width is set to a number high enough to be able to display the number of items per row, so that it doesn't push down overflowing items.

Non of the above works. Also in the code its showing two rows of 
`<ul><li>1,2,3,4</li></ul>`

```
<ul><li>1,2,3,4<li></ul>
```

instead of showing

```
<ul><li>1,2,3,4,5</li></ul>
```

so its not CSS issue.

**update**

I've this code in my list.phtml, do I add an addtional $_columnCount == 5 for this to work?
`

```
    $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 

    if($_columnCount == 4){
        $imgSize = 180;
    }elseif($_columnCount == 3){
        $imgSize = 245;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `column_count="5"` instead of `columnCount="5"`. And make sure the list template you are using has no hard coded values and makes use of `getColumnCount()`

Comment: hi its not working for me however I've checked list.phtml its has an if else column count line - i've updated in my question, not sure if I want a 5, do I add an additional in the if else statement?

Comment: You should have something like this: `<?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>`

Comment: yep i do have that and it doesn't have any hard coded values too.. so how around should i do it now?